# Can I record anticipatory key presses in PsychoPy?

Tags: python, psychopy, srt

I have a serial reaction time task in PsychoPy that will likely lead to participants pre-emptively entering key responses to future stimuli. This is what my current problem is:

> Correct answers: 1:A, 2:B, 3:C
>
> Stim: 1 -> Resp: A
>
> Stim: 2 -> Resp: B, Pre-emptive Resp: C
>
> Stim: 3 -> Resp: none recorded

Hence, I am missing data in the form of both reaction times and correct answers.

If I select 'all keys' in the component preferences, the correct response function ceases to work.

Is it possible to extend a permitted response window so that the 'begin' of a key response component is like a negative number (i.e., begin = -.5 s)?

Note: There is a cut-off for late responses, so overlapping correct answer periods is not an issue. What I'm trying to do is have the stimulus appearance and response windows be slightly out of phase with one another, with responses running a little ahead.

Comment: The logic of the experiment, your code, and analysis can be different. Nothing presents you from showing stims for a fixed duration and getting all key presses in that interval before moving to the next stimulus. Later, when analyzing your data, you can check if the returned list is of type None, meaning no keys pressed, or greater than length 1 meaning more keys pressed. Whether "extra" key presses are anticipatory is something you can look at when you analyze the data later by using any "second" key presses to Stim2 as possible answers to stim 3. If you have the times you can calc. Rt later.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm using a SRT format with thousands of trials, so manually scoring early answers isn't ideal. I'm going to explore using the 'all keys' preference, and then using a script to select the response that's closest  to the stimulus onset in either direction (e.g., 0.295 ms or the earlier trial's second response's negative value plus one)